# MS Word 2007 - Get back old menu style

Tags: microsoft-word

How can we get rid of the ribbon menu style in MS Word 2007 and replace it with old menu style (of MS Word 2003)?

I'm not comfortable with latest ribbon menu style?

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Easy.  Reinstall 2003.

Answer (score 1):

There are add-ons [like this one I found at first google](http://download.cnet.com/Classic-Menu-for-Word-2007/3000-2079_4-10637180.html), but I used to train nontechnical professors on the shift to 2007. I promise you could learn it with [a quick tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/interactive-word-2003-to-word-2007-command-reference-guide-HA010074432.aspx) and a few tries. Fight the temptation to become a ribbon curmudgeon... or damn yourself to never upgrading.

Good luck, 
mjb